# cockroachdb/kubernetes logging lots of errors on stackdriver

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-stackdriver, cockroachdb

I've just noticed from a very nasty gcp bill that cockroachDB has logged 1.5tb of errors on stackdriver, costing me several hundred dollars in just a few days. Sadly I had left it on 100% logging. The errors look like this and are piling up multiple times per second.

```
E  I180712 11:18:41.963205 106 server/status/runtime.go:223  [n2]
runtime stats: 1.5 GiB RSS, 283 goroutines, 254 MiB/54 MiB/441 MiB GO alloc/idle/total, 
918 MiB/1.1 GiB CGO alloc/total, 
2175.51cgo/sec, 
0.16/0.02 %(u/s)time, 0.00 %gc (1x)
```

Does anybody know what they mean, and how to stop them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all CockroachDB logs, not just errors. This is indicated by the `I` prefix (meaning `Info`) in the CockroachDB log line. The listed log lines show basic memory information for the `cockroach` process. This is logged every 10 seconds.

If you wish to persist logs I would recommend filtering by severity.

This can be done by CockroachDB itself when redirecting logs to stderr by using: `--logtostderr=Level` where `Level` is one of `Info`, `Warning`, `Error`, or `Fatal`.

If you are saving the raw logs, you could do a quick pass to discard anything not starting with a desired prefix. This will however not be as accurate as the `--logtostderr` method as you would need to handle multi-line log entries.

Comment: thanks for the hint - There's loads of other stuff logged as well. I used the standard GKE cockroach yaml file which contains --logtostderr option. The docs say the default was only to log warnings and errors, but i guess it must be logging info and debug  as well.  However GCP stackdriver interprets that an error rather than info, so filtering it out is not too easy. I'll have to see if I can figure out how to set the --logtostderr=Error without closing down the entire cluster

Answer (score 1):

[Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4966953/marc)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51305673/395927) is the "right" one, but as a workaround you could exclude specific logs from Stackdriver: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions

Log exclusions give fine grain control, and wouldn't require re-configuring or restarting the job.

Comment: Yes- thank you - I did filter the logging originally initially, but now I've restarted with different logging parameters and all is well.